# Add value from array and insert space

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a 2D array of integers, as seen in the main function. The program needs to prompt the user for a single integer. I then must add the user's value to each of the values in the 2D array using the 'addValue' function, as seen in the main function.

Then, write the 'print' function to print out the values in the array with each row of the array on its own line, and each number in each row separated by a single whitespace.

**NOTE: I should NOT print a whitespace after the last number on each line.**

Example:

```
Input:
2

Output:

7 6

25 1
```

The problem I have is that I need exactly to have a space in the output, but I only get that for certain input values. For example when input is **-1** I get 
output:

```
4 3

22-2      <- Notice that there is not an space.
```

Could someone help me fix it. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

void addValue(int my_array[][2],int value)
{
   for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
   {
       for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
       {
           my_array[i][j]=my_array[i][j]+value;  
       }
   }
}
void print(int my_array[][2])
{
   for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
   {
       for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
       {
        cout<<setw(2)<<my_array[i][j];  
    }
       cout<<endl;
   }
}

int main()
{
     int my_array[2][2] = {{5,4},{23,-1}};

     int value;
     cin >> value;

     addValue(my_array, value);

     print(my_array);

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Will your numbers always be 2 or less digits?  If not, then your issue is not only with the space, but with the `2` in your `setw()` call.

Answer (score 1):

```
cout<<setw(2)<<my_array[i][j];
```

outputs `my_array[i][j]` with a minimum spacing of 2 characters. If you have a value that takes 2 or more characters to display then... well here's an example:

```
std::cout << std::setw(1) << 42 << std::setw(2) << 42 << std::setw(3) << 42 << std::endl;
```

outputs

```
4242 42
```

So in the sample code 23 takes 2 characters and -1 takes 2 characters. They get crushed together and goes 23-1.

## Solution:

Force the space

```
cout<<setw(2)<<my_array[i][j] << ' ';
```

this can mess up the spacing of the columns and breaks the no space at the end of the line rule, so the other option is to ensure that the number passed into `setw` is large enough to maintain the spacing no matter what.

```
cout<<setw(100)<<my_array[i][j];
```

OK, that 100 is overkill, but you get the point. You could also put the space first.

```
cout<<setw(2)<<' ' << my_array[i][j];
```

No rule I see about a preceding space. Yet another option is to not bother with the inner `for` loop

```
cout << my_array[i][0] << ' ' << my_array[i][1];
```

if you have to preserve the `for` loop, print the first element without any adornment, then print the rest of the elements with a preceding space.

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    cout<< my_array[i][0];  
    for(int j=1;j<2;j++)
    {
        cout<< ' ' <<my_array[i][j];  
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```